# Error invoking chaincode: eventhub ::Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

On invoking chaincode i am obtaining below error.The peers are all up and working fine.Can anybody tell me what is going wrong"?

**Package.json**

```
   {
    "name": "Blockchain",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "description": "Hyperledger Fabric Application",
    "main": "app.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "fabric-ca-client": "1.1.0",
        "fabric-client": "1.1.0",
        "grpc": "^1.9.0"
    },
    "author": "ret",
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "keywords": [
        "Hyperledger",
        "Fabric",
    ]
}
```

**Error:**

```
Failed to invoke successfully :: Error: There was a problem with the eventhub ::Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The error was due to improper port mapping of event listener address. On mapping the right port in the invoke code, i was able to get the required results.